# w3wp automatically changes priority

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, iis-7

I have IIS7, and my w3wp process automatically changes priority. Process is started in normal priority, but after some time it becomes "below normal" and then "low". Also i can't force process priority by task manager, because process instantly switch to "low" priority. I have also other w3wp on same server, but i dont have such problem with them(they also change their priority, but for a short period of time).

I checked CPU limiting options of application pool and Quota system in registry.

Does IIS have some balancing mechanism that changes priority of web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I founded that priority had balanced by Windows System Resource Manager.